# CreatePen doesn't create memory leaks?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've created a HPEN and selected it with the following code:

```
HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0,0,0));
oldPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, hPen);
```

After this i'm drawing something and selecting the old Pen:

```
SelectObject(hdc, oldPen);
```

To see memory leaks i use:

```
#define CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>

/* This in the main function */
_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
```

If i close the application no mem leak will be shown. But i thought if i don't delete the object with *DeleteObject()* i get memory leaks.

I've tested the flag with this and it worked:

```
int* leak = new int;
```

So there can't be a problem with the flag.
Can you help me with this problem or tell me more about why no mem leak is shown?

Thank you!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CreatePen** is a *win32 api* function that (potentially) allocates some memory inside the windows kernel to be used while drawing. The memory allocated with *new* / *new[]* is allocated by the *C Run-Time Library* so it will be catch by the CRT debug functions. They were specifically created to catch memory leaks allocated with malloc / new / new[]

Comment: Thanks for the info! Will try other tools now.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, you will not be able to track down GDI leaks this way.

I personally use [*GDIView*](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html) for this purpose and am satisfied with it ( if others can recommend other tools for tracking down GDI leaks I would appreciate it ).

Also, you will need to delete the pen after you finish using it ( `DeleteObject(hPen)` ).

Best regards.